# Getting Object Data with Variable Python

Tags: python, object

I have an object like this:

```py
class Data():
    one = 'One'
    two = 'Two'
```

and I want to get that object value based on key variable we send through function like this:

```py
def showData(var):
    data = Data()
    return data[var]
print(showData('one'))
```

The result is not returning value, it's returning:

```py
TypeError: 'Data' object is not subscriptable
```

How to do that?

Comment: What is `one` and `two` in `data`?

Comment: `data = {one: 'One', two: 'Two'}` is not valid _unless_ you have defined variables `one` and `two`.

Comment: You need quotation marks around the keys in `data` if you're intending `one` and `two` to be strings. The syntax `{one: 'One', two: 'Two'}` could be valid if `one` and `two` are variables with some (hashable) values that you've defined above. But given the error you show, it sounds like they're undefined.

Comment: actually what you went,  show output what you need.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question, I have updated my question.

Comment: don't know if this works : return data[exec(var)]

Answer (score 0):

If `var` is always a string, use `getattr`:

```
class Data:
    a = 1
    b = 2

print(getattr(Data, "a"))
```

Use `hasattr` to check existence.